# How to write this query (if in sql and date )

Tags: sql

How to write the query

```
select MC_HOST_ADDRESS, LOCATION_TYPE , MC_LOCATION, MSG, STREET/SUBLOCATION, DURATION/( CLOSED_TIME - MC_ARRIVAL_TIME)
if  ( MC_ARRIVAL_TIME <  Start Date )  then   use Start Date  else  use End Date
where  
 MC_Object = ‘Camera’ AND
 MC_Parameter= ‘CameraFeed’ AND
(MC_ARRIVAL_TIME between Start Date and End Date)  OR
              ( CLOSED_TIME between Start Date and End Date) OR
         ( MC_ARRIVAL_TIME <=  Start Date and CLOSED_TIME >= End Date) OR
 ( MC_ARRIVAL_TIME <=  Start Date and CLOSED_TIME == NULL)enter code here`
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: 'if-else' can not be used in select, use 'case' instead

Comment: thanks for reply i did it ..... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE statement instead of IF clause in your query.

```
CASE WHEN MC_ARRIVAL_TIME <  StartDate  THEN  StartDate  ELSE   EndDate END
```

Comment: can you explain in brief

Comment: Please search for sql CASE statement . Its simple

Comment: for date should i use this  to_date(mension date )

Comment: for date comparison, both sides of comparison must have date data type ... so yes you need to use to_date() function to convert to date type if value is not in date form